# How to random a decimal number from maximum in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, logic

I already find a solution on this community but I can't find a solution.
My question is "How to random a decimal number from maximum in JavaScript?"

Example:
If I set Total to 1 and Size to 5, Then I want to generate a decimal number to an array(Size 5) that Sum total at 1.

```
Sum Total: 1
Array Size: 5
```

Result Array:

```
[0.23, 0.12, 0.4, 0.14, 0.11]
```

Thank you for all advice.
Best regards.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MTCoster My client want to have this function, But I never do like this before.

Comment: If you want help with a solution, you have to show us you’ve made an effort. The easiest way to do that is to show us what you’ve tried to make it work.

Comment: @MTCoster Now my client have to key it manually. But my customer want an automatic function that can do for them. I think if I know the solution I can do it by myself but now I don't know any logic of this function that can generate it automatically.

I already have a result only.

Comment: "*I already find […] but I can't find […].*" - Huh?

Comment: @WongsakornSuksiri Do you know how to generate an array of 5 numbers? If yes, that's the code you should start with. Please [edit] your question to show it - even if it doesn't completely work yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you want to generate an array of `n` numbers with a fixed sum (let’s call it `s`).

Let’s start by generating `n` random numbers. Javascript’s [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) creates numbers between 0 and 1, like this:

```js
function randomArray(length, sum) {
  return new Array(length).fill(0).map(() => Math.random());
}

const rand = randomArray(5, 1);
console.log(rand);

console.log('Sum: ', rand.reduce((a, b) => (a + b), 0));
```

This function creates a new array using the `length` parameter, fills it with `0` to initialize it, then replaces every element with a random number.

To meet the `sum` restriction, we need to do three things:

- Sum all the random numbers;
- Divide the desired sum by the calculated sum to acquire a scale factor, and
- Multiply every number by this scale factor.

```js
function randomArray(length, sum) {
  const rawRandom = new Array(length).fill(0).map(() => Math.random());
  const multiplier = sum / rawRandom.reduce((a, b) => (a + b), 0);
  return rawRandom.map(n => (n * multiplier));
}

const rand = randomArray(5, 1);
console.log(rand);

console.log('Sum: ', rand.reduce((a, b) => (a + b), 0));
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice and solution. You saved my life.

Thank you very much for your solution